# Convert type a to char

Tags: haskell

I have

```
data Dictionary a = Empty
                  | Branch (a, Bool, Dictionary a) (Dictionary a)
                  deriving (Ord, Eq)

instance Show (Dictionary a) where show = showDict

showDict (Branch (val, e, dict) dict2) = "My dict is : " ++ val
```

I know it is definitely wrong but I could not find how to write this one. In showDict function type of val is a but expected type is [Char].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn `val` into a string, `show` it:

```
showDict (Branch (val, e, dict) dict2) = "My dict is : " ++ show val
```

And don't forget the type constraints on `showDict`:

```
instance Show a => Show (Dictionary a) where show = showDict
```

Comment: I did but now the problem is `No instance for (Show a)`

Answer (score 1):

instance (Show a) => Show (Dictionary a) where show = showDict

You have to tell that a belongs to showable type class otherwise you can not use show on val .